# Entity Framework Code First - using UserId key of Memberships/Users table as Foreignkey in a custom table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am trying to create a `SQL` table to include additional user information.
I want it to be created by Migrations in VS2012 `(package console => update-database)`.

I see that there are two tables using UserId column as key: `Memberships and Users tables.`

I am trying to define the following class and map it to SQL table via Migrator:

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public Guid **UserId** { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    **public virtual User User { get; set; }**
```

Although it is obvious in the Users SQL table that UserId column is the key, I get this error message:

```
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'User' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'Users' is based on type 'User' that has no keys defined.
```

What I am missing here? Might be that `Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.User / System.Web.Security.MembershipUser` classes weren't necessarily mapped to the tables this way and vise versa, and therefore the `UserId` property is not declared is Key dataannotation?

I am open for other solutions for this problem.

Big Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using asp.net mvc4 with Azure db.

When I want to use UserId in other tables from UserProfile. Notice in AccountModels there is class UserProfile:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, let's say your category is created by certain user, you can link category entry to user in following way.

```
[Table("Category")]
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile CreatorUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise, you can always use UserProfile as model.